# flutter/dart: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 5140 pos 12: '_history.isNotEmpty': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart

I have used ****persistent_bottom_nav_bar: ^5.0.2**** and I have used bunch of pages and every page has app bar and on app bar is logout button when I try to logout It throw this mentioned exception.(Long story short).
any help would be appreciated thanks.
the following is scenario like which I have implemented :

```
  class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
      const LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
    }
    
    class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
      GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            body: ListView(
              children: [
                Form(
                  key: formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      FloatingActionButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                            if (accessToken != null) {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => MultiProvider(
                                    providers: [
                                      ChangeNotifierProvider<DashboardProvider>(
                                          create: (context) => DashboardProvider()),
                                    ],
                                    child: Dashboard(),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            }
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
      Dashboard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      static PersistentTabController controller =
          PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);
      @override
      State<Dashboard> createState() => _DashboardState();
    }
    
    class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
      List<Widget> _buildScreen() {
        return [
          HomePage(),
          FoTotalOrdersLocation(),
        ];
      }
    
      List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navigationBarItems() {
        return [
          PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home,
              size: 30,
            ),
            textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            title: ("Home"),
          ),
          PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.location_on,
              size: 30,
            ),
            textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            title: ("Location"),
          ),
        ];
      }
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        if (Dashboard.controller.index == 0) {}
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        print("build called");
        return Scaffold(
          body: ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (context) => FoHomePageProvider(context),
            child: PersistentTabView(
              context,
              controller: Dashboard.controller,
              screens: _buildScreen(),
              items: _navigationBarItems(),
              onItemSelected: (val) async {},
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
      const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.popUntil(
                  context,
                  ModalRoute.withName(' /loginPage'),
                );
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.logout),
            ),
          ),
          body:ElevatedButtonWidget(
                    text: "Next",
                   
                    onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) =>  UsersPage(),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                       
                  ),
        );
      }
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class UsersPage extends StatelessWidget {
      const UsersPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.popUntil(
                  context,
                  ModalRoute.withName(' /loginPage'),
                );
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.logout),
            ),
          ),
          body: Text("Users page"),
        );
      }
    }
```

when I try to logout the following exception is thrown :

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building Navigator(dirty, dependencies: [UnmanagedRestorationScope, HeroControllerScope], state: NavigatorState#5900b(tickers: tracking 0 tickers)):
'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 5140 pos 12: '_history.isNotEmpty': is not true.
package:flutter/…/widgets/navigator.dart:5140
2
```

Comment: What exception does it throw?

Comment: ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building Navigator(dirty, dependencies: [UnmanagedRestorationScope, HeroControllerScope], state: NavigatorState#5900b(tickers: tracking 0 tickers)):
'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 5140 pos 12: '_history.isNotEmpty': is not true.
package:flutter/…/widgets/navigator.dart:5140
2

Comment: @TarHalda if you have idea kindly share with us

Comment: sorry, I don't :-( That's not an error I've heard of before.